# Detecting vandalism in SQL Server

Tags: database, security, sql-server-2008

Over the past several months I've seen quite a few unexpected bugs popping up in a legacy application, most of which are related to inconsistencies between the application code (classic ASP) and the underlying SQL Server database.

For example, a user reported a 500 error on a page last week that has been working correctly for five years. I discovered that the page in question was looking for a column in a result set named "AllowEditDatasheets", while the real column name was "AllowDatasheetEdit".

Normally I'd attribute this to publishing untested code but, as I said, the page has been working correctly for a very long time.

I've run across this quite a few times recently - pages that never should have worked but have been.

I'm starting to suspect that another employee is making subtle changes to the database, such as renaming columns. Unfortunately, there are several applications that use a common login that was granted SA rights, and removing those rights would break a lot of code (Yes, I know this is poor design - don't get me started), so simply altering account permissions isn't a viable solution.

I'm looking for a way to track schema changes. Ideally, I'd be able to capture the IP address of the machine that makes these sorts of changes, as well as the change that was made and the date/time when it occurred.

I know I can create a scheduled process that will script the database and commit the scripts to our source control system, which will let me know when these chages occurr, but that doesn't really help me find the source.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I would guess dbas/server admins woulld be better people to answer such a question.

Comment: @AndrewBarber most of the SQL admins I've talked to aren't really familiar with this type of thing, but I'll happily migrate the question to another site if it belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default trace already tracks schema changes.

In Management Studio you can right click the node of the database of interest and from the reports menu view the report "Schema Changes History" that pulls its data from there.

If the information recorded there is not sufficient you can add a [DDL trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406.aspx) to perform your own logging (e.g. recording [`HOST_NAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598.aspx) though that can be spoofed)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 and above, you can use [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx).

With earlier versions, you may be able to add triggers to the system tables that hold schema information and log changes to those.

Comment: +1 I hadn't explored audits before; should come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

That's just as bad as GRANT DBA TO PUBLIC!.. You best rewrite code and restrict SA privilege to one or few DBA's!.. Column renaming is not the only thing they could wreak havoc upon!.. Having a common login-ID is also not a good idea because you have no way of pinpointing exactly who did what.

Comment: Rewriting isn't a viable option at this point, as I've said.

Comment: So as long as you don't re-write the code to make the system more secure, whoever is sabotaging the system knows this weakness and will continue to exploit it and you'll end up with obfuscated code which will eventually render the system unusable!.. Even if you were to implement audit trails, it will be of no value to you!.. At least, get rid of the common login-id and replace it with unique id's with SA privs so you can know who did what.. The SYSTEM id should only be used by the DBA(s).

Comment: All of your points are valid and well-known. However, again, rewriting isn't an option. We're talking about a dozen applications in nearly as many languages, maintained by quite a few different people. One in particular has 500k+ line code base and, before I came along, it was written to depend on the ability to modify database metadata. Unless you and your friends are willing to pitch in on a rewrite, it ain't gonna happen this century.

Comment: Well, at least have one login ID account per user and assign DBA privs to whoever requires it. That way you can pinpoint who did what, and if you create an audit file for critical tables that will help you nail the sucker!.. Does your shop have source code control?.. Is there any kind of system accounting log files or journaling?.. Can you sumarize what the app does?.. I'll pitch in for the re-write, for a fee, I'm legendary for putting out fires :)

Comment: Restrict access to the source code with the following method: Your SCCS should be implemented with a check-out/check-in method where all code requests are funneled through an SCCS administrator. Once the developer has modified and tested the code, it is sent back to the SCCS admin for review and approval before being installed into the production system. You can also do random code peer reviews. Its time consuming, but will eliminate the problems!

Comment: That would require a full-time source control admin that is intimately familiar with the code base. Different users have different accounts but, again, some of the apps require the ability to modify the database schema, and tightening down source control access won't have any affect on a vandal making changes to a production system. Yes, it's poor design, but a few of these apps were started in the late 1990s, and I simply don't have the resources to fix the situation without taking mission-critical systems offline for an indeterminate period.

Comment: How often is the schema modified?.. Can schema changes be funneled through a DBA?.. Even changing only one column could render the whole system unusable if that column is in a system control table or other critical column which is globally used. Continue to use exiting system and seriously consider re-writing it to tighten up security.